# Eloquent model events not firing when using relations

Tags: events, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a typical event hook for soft deleting children:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleted(function($model1)
    {
        $model1->hasmanyrelation()->delete();
    });
}
```

and

```
public function hasmanyrelation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Model2');
}
```

Now when I use:

```
$model0->model1->each(function($model1){$model1->delete();});
```

things work as expected and model2 children of model 1 get (soft) deleted. But when I use:

```
$model0->model1()->delete();
```

then all related model1 records get deleted but model2 and all its records remain untouched. What is wrong with the latter, simpler syntax that it deletes model1 records but skips its model events??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an old one still it may help someone...

Models should be "pulled" first to trigger an event.

[See Official Answer Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536)

Comment: Same thing happens with update. Had me scratching my head for a while, but the reason makes sense. You need to instantiate a model instance and delete or update it explicitly before any events are fired. Statements such as `$model->where(...)->update([...]);` just run SQL and so don't involve the models and events.

Answer (score 1):

refactor this :

```
$model1->hasmanyrelation()->delete();
```

to

```
$models = $model1->hasmanyrelation;
foreach($models as $model){
    $model->delete()
}
```